# Convert excel to custom list of dicts in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Say i have an excel, which is start from row 5 (first 4 rows are some kind of metadata, which should be skipped) like so:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val a | another val c |
| 2 | val b | another val d |

and i have a list which should be a key of each cell value:

`headers = ["no", "val1", "val2"]`

how can i achieve those excel to list of dicts like so:

`excl = [{"no":"1", "val1": "val", "val2":"another val"},{"no":"2", "val1": "val", "val2":"another val"}]`

i've tried this:

```
data = []
wb = load_workbook("raw.xlsx")
sheet = wb['Sheetname']

headers = ["no", "val1", "val2"]

for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5): #because there is a 'trash' data in first 5 rows that i wanna get rid of
    for cell in row_cells:
        for i in headers: 
            obj = dict()
            obj[i] = cell.value
            data.append(obj)
```

the reason is that i wanna return them as json response for frontend.

Comment: You recreate the dictionary for **each** item in your headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make 3 iterations (2 nested), iterate over rows, columns, and then headers. This will create objects with a length of (rows * columns * headers)

My solution is just iterate over rows and columns:

```
for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5): #because there is a 'trash' data in first 5 rows that i wanna get rid of   
    obj = dict()            
    for i in range(1, len(row_cells)):               
        obj[headers[i]] = row_cells[i].value
    data.append(obj)
```

Print the output:

```
print(data[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done without iterating/looping using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('raw.xlsx', sheets=0, skiprows=range(1,4))

df= df.rename(columns={'x':'no', 'y':'val1', 'z':'val2'})
dicto =df.to_dict(orient='records')

print(dicto)
```